# Retraining fingers with instant feedback (for a future without Esc key)

Tags: macos, keyboard, vim

Preparing for the future and protecting my wrists, I've remapped some keys that I commonly type (eg for escape, I now press/release caps lock; for control, I hold caps lock with another key, for caps lock I press both shift keys).

But I'd like to have an alert, some instant feedback when my old fingers type the forbidden keys. So if I type `ESC` or `CONTROL_L`, I'd like nothing to happen and the screen to flash or beep or both. Flashing red would of course be delightful.

Going one step further, I also wouldn't mind trying out having an alert when I use the "wrong" `SHIFT` for capital letters and special chars, to see if that might help me break some old habits.

Is this possible?

Comment: You managed to remap some keys, why not just do the same thing remap the other keys to "nothing" and/or to trigger some kind of popup?  What software are you using to remap the keys you've already done, and what have you attempted so far to reach your goal?

Comment: I was hacking around with Karabiner, but it only got me half way. I would be surprised if there wasn't a better alternative. If not, I'll post what I managed to get working as a partial answer.

Comment: Never moving your wrists is quite possibly the worst thing to do if you want to protect them.

Comment: @romaini I don't understand what you're trying to say here

Answer (score 1):

The following is how I got what I wanted. Using `tput bel` and other shell commands didn't seem to work, but using `osascript -e "beep 1"` did. I added a second beep to make the effect more obvious.

1. Install Karabiner and Seil
2. Set Caps Lock Key to "No Action" in OSX Keyboard Preferences (Modifier keys)
3. Set Caps Lock to send code 110 using Seil
4. Add the following private XML in Karabiner and enable each resulting item.

Karabiner private XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
 <vkopenurldef>
    <name>KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_SHELL_beep</name>
    <url type="shell">
      <![CDATA[    /usr/bin/osascript -e "beep 2" ]]>
    </url>
  </vkopenurldef>
  <item>
    <name>Change escape key to beep</name>
    <identifier>private.escape_to_beep</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_SHELL_beep</autogen>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Left control key to beep</name>
    <identifier>private.left_control_key_to_beep</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_SHELL_beep</autogen>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Application key to Control_R key</name>
    <appendix>(+ When you type Control_R only, send Escape)</appendix>
    <identifier>private.application2controlR_escape</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::PC_APPLICATION, KeyCode::CONTROL_R, KeyCode::ESCAPE</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

I might programmatically expand this to do the same for things like using the wrong shift key.